# How to draw commit history in JavaFX with JGit

Tags: javafx, jgit

I want to use JavaFX to draw a git graphic history using JGit.

Can you give me an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JGit provides an `AbstractPlotRenderer` that is meant to draw the commit history in a table widget.

Subclass this class and its related classes `PlotCommitList` and `PlotLane` to show a Git history in JavaFX.

There is also an `AWTPlotRenderer` that may serve as a template.